# Getting parse error on using head function on a list in haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I have a function, ground n p, with two input parameters n and p, that returns like this: [[1,0,1],[0,0,1],[1,1,1]]. I am doing the following to take the head of this list of lists and do computation.

```
enter =
  lst <- head (ground)
  map (\x -> if (x == 0) then 2 else x) lst
```

But, I get the following error: parse error on input ‘<-’

Why is it so?

I new to haskell and have just begun learning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<-` is used in `do` notation for monads.
I think what you want is this:

```
enter ground =
  let lst = head ground
  in map (\x -> if (x == 0) then 2 else x) lst
```

here I use the usual `let ... in ...` syntax to define `lst = head ground` - of course `ground` has to be defined somewhere else. As I don't see it I made `enter` into a function that takes it as an argument.

Or using a function `ground` (your comment)

```
enter =
  let lst = head . ground $ yourArgumentsForGroundHere
  in map (\x -> if (x == 0) then 2 else x) lst
```

An alternative is this:

```
enter (lst:_) =
  map (\x -> if (x == 0) then 2 else x) lst
```

Here I use pattern matching to get `lst` out of the argument of `enter`.

You can also do it with composition:

```
enter = map (\x -> if (x == 0) then 2 else x) . head
```

where you don't need to name the argument anymore and use `.` instead.

#### using do notation

maybe this is not the best point for an novice but in `do` notation you could write it
like this:

```
enter ground = head $ do
  lst <- ground
  return $ map (\x -> if (x == 0) then 2 else x) lst
```

here you *pull* out every `lst` inside the argument `ground` and then use your `map` to
transform it and yield them all into another list `return` - of course here you have to do `head` afterwards to just get the first.

Of course this is only for demonstration where the `<-` might be used - don't write it like this.

Comment: Yes, I think your first explanation is what I'm wanting to do. Of course, I have a ground function. But, so when I do this, I'm getting the following error: Couldn't match type ‘[Int]’ with ‘Int’
    Expected type: [Int]
      Actual type: [[Int]]
Like I wrote in my question, ground has a return type of [[Int]]; what to do in this case?

Comment: If you have another function `ground` then you have to get the result from it and put it into enter: `enter . ground $ yourArgumentForGroundHere` - I cannot make it more clean without seeing your ground

Comment: I have added this to the answer

Comment: `enter [lst,_] =` only matches two elements.

Comment: @CarstenKönig `(lst,_)` isn't even a list :P. Looking for `(lst:_)`?

Comment: @alternative not my day ... I'm kindof sick right now - sorry again